# UI-router nested view not being injected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a root `index.html` file which has a ui-view tag, to which a main template file `home.html` is injected.

`home.html` has a `ui-view` tag which needs to change depending on the current route. I followed the official ui-router documentation and wrote the `app.js`, but the nested `ui-view` in `home.html` tag is not being injected with a view.

The structure is as follows:

```
index.html
   | home.html
      - dashboard.html
      - tables.html
```

`index.html` has a ui-view tag which shows `home.html`. `home.html` is a template with a `ui-view` tag which needs to either show `dashboard.html` or `tables.html` depending on the route.

Source:

index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/main.min.css"/>
  <script src="lib/js/main.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
      <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/home.html -

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div ng-include="sidebar.html" scope="" onload=""></div>
<!-- End Sidebar -->

<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div class="page-content">

    <!-- Header Bar -->
    <div ng-include="header.html" scope="" onload=""></div>
    <!-- End Header Bar -->

    <!-- Main Content -->

    <div ui-view></div>

  </div><!-- End Page Content -->
</div><!-- End Content Wrapper -->
```

module.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies']);
```

routes.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For unmatched routes
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // Application routes
    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })

        .state('home.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
        })

        .state('home.tables', {
            url: '/tables',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

On add them as routes without inheriting from `home`, they're being injected normally into `index.html`, which means it's not an issue with the route themselves.

How can I inherit the template and inject the views, depending on the route?

Comment: There's an error: `<div ng-include="header.html" scope="" onload=""` add `>` at the end

Comment: Yes, sorry that was an issue only when writing the question. On removing `abstract: true` from the parent route, the header and sidebar are visible, only ui-view remains uninjected, so that's not the problem.

Comment: question is unclear, what do you mean by *nested ui-view tag is not getting?* Please explain whole scenario. add plunkr with problem statement, that would be appreciable

Comment: I added a bit clarifying the structure (please do tell if it is still not clear). I'll add plunkr with the problem statement in a while.
By 'ui-view not getting' I just meant the child views were not getting injected into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. I removed the `url` tag from abstract state `home`, and just set `home.dashboard` to `/`.

This works:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For unmatched routes
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // Application routes
    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })

        .state('home.dashboard', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
        })

        .state('home.tables', {
            url: '/tables',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ui-router as a dependency to the module

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router'])
```

also make sure you have added references

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/EWDVf0RDfzvo8oPH9kdM/)**

Comment: Sorry, missed adding my module.js file to the question. I've imported the dependencies.